# OpenCV: record footage in one window and Display the same video in 2nd window but with contours only

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to capture a video and display it on one window and have second window in which contours are displayed simultaneous. I am struggling with how to have the processed video displayed in the second window. Please analyze my code and suggest a solution or indicate where am going wrong maybe give me some directions to an online tutorial or sources. Thanks.

```
     #include "iostream"
    #include<opencv\cv.h>
    #include<opencv\highgui.h>
    #include<opencv\ml.h>
    #include<opencv\cxcore.h>
    #include <iostream> 
    #include <vector>
    #include <string> 
    #include <opencv2/core/core.hpp> // Basic OpenCV structures (cv::Mat)
    #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp> // Video write

    using namespace cv;
    using namespace std;


    Mat image; Mat image_gray; Mat image_gray2; Mat threshold_output;
    Mat frame;
    int thresh=100, max_thresh=255;


    int main(int argc, char** argv) {

     //Capture Video
     VideoCapture capCam(1);
     if (!capCam.isOpened()){
        cout<<"ERROR: Failed to Initialize Camera"<<endl;
        return 1;
     }
     else{
        cout<<"Camera Initialized"<<endl;
     }

 //Create Window
char* ImputFootage = "Source";
namedWindow(ImputFootage, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow(ImputFootage, frame);

char* OutputFootage = "Processed";
namedWindow(OutputFootage, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow(OutputFootage, frame);



 while(1){
    capCam>> frame;
    imshow("Source", frame);
    return(1);

    if(capCam.read(ImputFootage)){

        //Convert Image to gray & blur it
cvtColor( image, 
    image_gray, 
    CV_BGR2GRAY );

blur( image_gray, 
    image_gray2,
    Size(3,3) );
//Threshold Gray&Blur Image
threshold(image_gray2, 
    threshold_output, 
    thresh, 
    max_thresh, 
    THRESH_BINARY);

//2D Container
vector<vector<Point>> contours;

//Fnd Countours Points, (Imput Image, Storage, Mode1, Mode2, Offset??)
findContours(threshold_output,
    contours, // a vector of contours
    CV_RETR_EXTERNAL,// retrieve the external contours
    CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE,
    Point(0, 0)); // all pixels of each contours    

// Draw black contours on a white image
Mat result(threshold_output.size(),CV_8U,Scalar(255));
drawContours(result,contours,
    -1, // draw all contours
    Scalar(0), // in black
    2); // with a thickness of 2


    }
 }
char CheckForEscKey = waitKey(10);
return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call `imshow("Processed", result);` after calling `drawContours`

Answer (score 0):

You were trying to show frames even before they were captured with camera. Compiler was not giving you error because Mat were declared ,but they were  without value (null), Moreover you were trying to display Mat image, but what you capture from camera is Mat frame. Also, you lack exit (esc sequence, and your wait key was OUT of camera loop.

Anyway, here is your code (rewritten), I hope this is what you wanted.

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

Mat image;
Mat image_gray;
Mat image_gray2;
Mat threshold_output;
Mat frame;
int thresh = 100, max_thresh = 255;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    //Capture Video
    VideoCapture capCam(0);
    if (!capCam.isOpened())
    {
        cout << "ERROR: Failed to Initialize Camera" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Camera Initialized" << endl;
    }

    //Create Window
    char* ImputFootage = "Source";
    namedWindow(ImputFootage, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    char* OutputFootage = "Processed";
    namedWindow(OutputFootage, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    while (1)
    {
        capCam >> frame;
        imshow(ImputFootage, frame);

        if (capCam.read(frame))
        {

            //Convert Image to gray & blur it
            cvtColor(frame, image_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

            blur(image_gray, image_gray2, Size(3, 3));
            //Threshold Gray&Blur Image
            threshold(image_gray2, threshold_output, thresh, max_thresh, THRESH_BINARY);

            //2D Container
            vector<vector<Point> > contours;

            //Fnd Countours Points, (Imput Image, Storage, Mode1, Mode2, Offset??)
            findContours(threshold_output, contours, // a vector of contours
                    CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, // retrieve the external contours
                    CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE, Point(0, 0)); // all pixels of each contours

            // Draw black contours on a white image
            Mat result(threshold_output.size(), CV_8U, Scalar(255));
            drawContours(result, contours, -1, // draw all contours
                    Scalar(0), // in black
                    2); // with a thickness of 2

            imshow(OutputFootage, result);

            char CheckForEscKey = waitKey(10);

            //If the key pressed by user is Esc(ASCII is 27) then break out of the loop
            if (CheckForEscKey == 27)
            {
                break;
            }

        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```