# How to store point co-ordinates in vector data type in opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a Mat object (CV_8UC1) which is a binary map with 1's on some positions and zeros otherwise.I want to create a vector which stores the co-ordinates of the points where the Mat is 1.Any suggestions on how to go about it.
I know that I can loop around the image and check points with the following code

```
for( int p = 1; p <= img.rows; p++ )
    { for( int q = 1; q <= img.cols; q++ )
        {
            if(  img.at<uchar>(p,q) == 1 )
            {
                //what to do here ? 
            }
        }
    }
```

Also, I need the co-ordinates to be single precision floating point numbers.This is to use it as an input for another function which requires vectors.
Please gimme a hint.I am not familiar with vector data types and STL.

Comment: Have you tried to read a few examples of std::vector? It is pretty straight forward :), you could also have a look at SO Documentation: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/511/stdvector#t=201607281304324915589

Comment: By the way, your loops will fail with an access violation exception if you try to launch your program. Try to learn how zero-based indices work in most modern programming languages.

Comment: Aah that was a silly mistake.BTW I do understand zero based indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find all non-zero coordinates in a binary map with OpenCV, th ebest is to use [findNonZero](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gaed7df59a3539b4cc0fe5c9c8d7586190).

Here is an example of how to use it (with a dummy matrix but you get the idea):

```
cv::Mat img(100, 100, CV_8U, cv::Scalar(0));
img.at<uchar>(50, 50) = 255;
img.at<uchar>(70, 50) = 255;
img.at<uchar>(58, 30) = 255;

cv::Mat nonZeroes;

cv::findNonZero(img, nonZeroes);

std::vector<cv::Point2f> coords(nonZeroes.total());

for (int i = 0; i < nonZeroes.total(); i++) {
    coords[i] = nonZeroes.at<cv::Point>(i);
}
```

Comment: `vector<Point> coords; findNonZero(img, coords);` is far better.. ;D

Comment: @Miki  But if you want floating-point coordinates, you will have to convert them in a second step anyway. Even though I can't imagine why you would want floating point coordinates here...

Comment: Actually I want to use these coordinate in cv::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(prev_gray, curr_gray, features_prev, features_next, status, err); as features_prev and if I am reading the documentation correctly features_prev should be of type std::vector<cv::Point2f> http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#calcopticalflowpyrlk
 Although I don't understand myself why it would require the coords to be floating point.

Comment: @Sunreef Bro your code doesn't work.
It gives the following error.
error: call of overloaded ‘Point_(cv::Point_<int>&)’ is ambiguous
  on the line where    coords[i] = cv::Point2f(nonZeroes.at<cv::Point>(i));
Any suggestions?

Comment: @HassanJaved  I don't get this error with OpenCV 3.1.0. What happens if you replace this line with `cv::Point pt = nonZeroes.at<cv::Point>(i);
 coords[i] = cv::Point2f(pt.x, pt.y);`?

Comment: As pointed out in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18063003/call-of-overloaded-point-cvpoint2f-is-ambiguous), there is a known bug in OpenCV 2.4.3. I'll edit the code to reflect this. @HassanJaved

Comment: I am using opencv 2.4.11 and yea declaring an intermediate point does work but it is very slow.Another thing is that I've checked the points and there values before and after conversion are very different.e.g a point[221 1] after conversion to Point2f becomes [3.09687e-43 1.4013e-45].What's this?

Comment: Well my bad , actually the points differ because I was playing with it by using   coords[i] = nonZeroes.at<cv::Point2f>(i);

Comment: @HassanJaved   The assignment operator should work, even if the constructor doesn't. Take a look at the code in my answer, I removed the `cv::Point2f` constructor.